# doctrine SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column -after delete column in Mysql

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I deleted two columns in table user, later I just deleted property, getter and setter from User.php class.

Problem is:

```
File:

C:\xampp1_8\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException.php:91
```

Message:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.usr_name AS usr_name1, t0.usr_password AS usr_password2, t0.usr_email AS usr_email3, t0.usrl_id AS usrl_id4, t0.usr_question AS usr_question5, t0.usr_answer AS usr_answer6, t0.usr_picture AS usr_picture7, t0.usr_password_salt AS usr_password_salt8, t0.usr_registration_date AS usr_registration_date9, t0.usr_registration_token AS usr_registration_token10, t0.usr_email_confirmed AS usr_email_confirmed11, t0.usr_id AS usr_id12 FROM users t0':

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.usrl_id' in 'field list'
```

I use ZF2 with Doctrine module

Comment: .\vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --force

Comment: And regenerate proxies